# How do I convert a ValueNotifier into a Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some value notifiers on my code (**TextEdittingController**) and I would like to convert them into Streams, so I can use `rx_dart`'s Observable.combineLatest to check if all of them are empty at once on my code, returning the result of the check (**bool**) and embedding it into only one `StreamBuilder`.

Something like that:

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
          stream: Observe.combineLatest2(STREAM1, STREAM2, (s1,s2) => s1.text.isNotEmpty && s2.text.isNotEmpty),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == true) {
              return ShowUp.fifth(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    child: Text("Finish"),
                    onPressed: _finishPressed,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        )
```

How do I convert a ValueNotifier into a Stream?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: The one I posted below is working for me. But it's not pretty...

Answer (score 3):

The solution I came with is that one, but I don't know if it's the correct way of doing it. I will share it here but I hope someone comes with a better purpose:

**REMEMBER**: you have to call it's close method after using it or it will leak.

```
class ValueNotifierStream<T> extends Stream<T> {
  final ValueNotifier _valueNotifier;
  final _subject = BehaviorSubject<T>();
  VoidCallback _notifierCallback;

  ValueNotifierStream(this._valueNotifier) {
    _subject.add(_valueNotifier.value);

    _notifierCallback = () {
      _subject.add(_valueNotifier.value);
    };

    _valueNotifier.addListener(_notifierCallback);
  }

  @override
  StreamSubscription<T> listen(
    void Function(T event) onData, {
    Function onError,
    void Function() onDone,
    bool cancelOnError,
  }) {
    return _subject.listen(
      onData,
      onError: onError,
      onDone: onDone,
      cancelOnError: cancelOnError,
    );
  }

  void close() {
    _valueNotifier.removeListener(_notifierCallback);
    _subject.close();
  }
}
```